# Как получить File изображения из resources собранного jar

Tags: java, файлы, jar, resources

Необходимо прочитать `png` изображение из папки `resources`. Стркутура папок такая: `resources/img-storage/dashboard/empty.png`.

Я использую такую конструкцию:

```
String path = "img-storage" + File.separator + "dashboard" + File.separator + "empty.png";
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
String absolutePath = cl.getResource(path).getPath();

File result = new File(absolutePath);
System.out.println(result.exist()); //-> false
```

Когда я распаковываю `jar` то так эти папки и файл есть а программа падает c `Can't read input file!` ...

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at org.robinhood.model.Dashboard.isEmpty(Dashboard.java:91)
    at org.robinhood.manager.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:44)
    at org.robinhood.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Dashboard scanning is fail! see: class org.robinhood.model.Dashboard
    at org.robinhood.model.Dashboard.isEmpty(Dashboard.java:102)
    at org.robinhood.manager.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:44)
    at org.robinhood.Application.main(Application.java:17)
```

В общем файл не находит а в `IDE` все реботает верно.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. У меня в ресурсах `img-storage` к которому я все время должен обращаться за `png` файлами в виде объектов `File`. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуй путь начинать с resources/

Comment: @RodGers пробовал не помогаетет, после этого и полез jar распаковывать, и увидел что там вообще нет папки resources&

Comment: через что делаешь jar?

Comment: @Pavel, может вам InputStream будет достаточно? Тогда, InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileFromJarFile);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/6366534

Comment: @RodGers через maven

Comment: @Oleg A у меня там структура папок и много изображений и уже отлажен механизм обхода этой структуры и выбора нужных изображений. Если я пойду по пути со стримами то мне придется очень много переписать((( а не хотелось бы...

Comment: Ну, как вам уже дали ссылку на so, нельзя прочитать File из zip, чем является jar

Comment: @Oleg A ок спасибо я не знал что jar это zip